# How for force all new Wifi network connections to be PRIVATE?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-firewall, windows-defender

I found how to do this with a router or ethernet card. With the wifi adapter, each connection is treated as a new one.

I set up Windows Defender firewall to block non-VPN traffic, following this guide:
zorrovpn(dot)com/articles/windows-firewall-vpn-only?lang=en
(I use a different VPN, but this works.)

Network connections need to be PRIVATE for this to work.  I set this up at home, and it works fine.

I went to a coffee shop, and Windows connected as PUBLIC, so the firewall rules fail, and traffic is allowed without the VPN being connected.  I manually changed the connection type to PRIVATE by right-clicking on the Windows task bar network icon, and selecting properties.

I need all new network connections to default to PRIVATE, so I don't have to remember to manually change it.  How do I do that?  I want to persist across any Windows updates. Hard coded, so nothing can change it.

Thanks.

(Windows 10 Home edition -> "Private" OR "Public" ; not public/work/home in Pro edition.)

Comment: Could you not just set up the same firewall rules against the public profile? Sounds like the easier answer. In fact, it'd make more sense for this kind of filtering to be applied to public over private anyway.

Comment: I assume there's a reason Zorro VPN says to do it this way. The only other step-by-step guide to making a firewall VPN kill switch with Windows Defender Firewall did it exactly the same way.  -- Windows Firewall is complicated and non-intuitive to me. I preferred doing this with Comodo (intuitive), but Comodo kept getting corrupted, so I removed it.

Comment: Ah... I think I see why ... I suspect they're expecting the VPN pseudo-network adapter to be categorised as public, and therefore allowing connections through it. You could perhaps invert this (set the VPN pseudo-network adapter as a private network, allow outbound on private and block on public, set all other networks as public) as an alternative.